# bash conditional statement OR regex

Tags: regex, bash, if-statement, logic

I have a test file that logs the number of failures on the last line. I determine whether the test passed by checking for this line. Due to a bug a passed test will always have one failure. A passed line looks like the following:

```
FAILED : - Failures   = 1
```

My code to date which works is:

```
if [[ $(tail -n 1 temp.txt) != "FAILED : - Failures   = 1" ]]; then 
   echo "FAILED"
fi
```

However with a different software branch the word `'FAILED'` has been replaced with `'WARNING'` e.g.

```
WARNING : - Failures   = 1
```

I'm trying to write a regex to OR the words `'WARNING'` and `'FAILED'` but so far it's not working.

Comment: You could try `[A-Z]*`. You won't need to OR anything that way. But this way would match any uppercase alpha characters. So if you ever have something like `SUCCESS: - Failures  =1` it will match, but I highly doubt that will happen. Although I'm not sure if `bash` itself can handle such regex. Perhaps `sed` or `awk` will work though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use extglob:

```
if [[ $(tail -n 1 temp.txt) != @(WARNING|FAILED)" : - Failures   = 1" ]]
then
  echo "FAILED"
fi
```

`@(pattern1|pattern2|..)` is a bash glob that matches either of the given patterns.

Depending on your input, you can use further pattern matching to make your matching more resilient. For example, strings containing the word "WARNING" or "FAILED" followed by the word "Failures" can be matched with

```
[[ $(tail -n 1 temp.txt) != *@(WARNING|FAILED)*"Failures"* ]]
```

---

Fun fact: extglobs are regular expressions, they just don't use the canonical syntax that other UNIX tools do.